# Bash count lines and pipe into less info

Tags: bash, curl, awk

Im strugling to get the info i want, we are using a spamfilter which can be monitored thru API calls.

We use PRTG as our monitoring, PRTG is calling a Bash script which calls the API using curl.

The info i need to work with is called by this line.

```
queue=$(curl -u USER:PASS -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/http" https://mx10.mailfilter.nl/cgi-bin/api?call=api_delivery_queue&sort_field=domain,server)



OUTPUT:(lines below the domain are associated with te domain)
domain1.TLD
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1csiOn-00012P-QL,2017-03-28 21:08:29
mx20.mailfilter.nl,1csLqx-0004fO-EM,2017-03-28 21:08:29
domain2.TLD
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1csvTq-0007a4-MS,2017-03-28 21:08:29
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1csvhh-0000gI-5s,2017-03-28 21:08:29
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1cswCX-0004bQ-Iz,2017-03-28 21:08:29
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1csvk3-00013I-Rx,2017-03-28 21:08:29
domain3.TLD
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1csbxg-0005sG-Px,2017-03-28 21:08:29
```

I need to break this down to: (where the number is the count of lines associated with the domain)
Expected Output :

```
domain1.TLD 2
domain2.TLD 4
domain3.TLD 1

totalcount=$(curl -u USER:PASS -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/http" https://mx10.mailfilter.nl/cgi-bin/api?call=api_get_delivery_queue_count&domain=default)
```

Which at the end echos 0:$totalcount:$queue

EDIT:(29-03)

My example might be not as clear as i ment it to be :)

domain1.TLD
domain2.TLD
..
Are just some examples the variantion of domains is enormous. From a to z. The lines that are static start with mx10 or mx20.

The command from Vipin might do the trick i will try that one tomorrow.

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$ cat f
domain1.TLD
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1csiOn-00012P-QL,2017-03-28 21:08:29
mx20.mailfilter.nl,1csLqx-0004fO-EM,2017-03-28 21:08:29
domain2.TLD
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1csvTq-0007a4-MS,2017-03-28 21:08:29
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1csvhh-0000gI-5s,2017-03-28 21:08:29
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1cswCX-0004bQ-Iz,2017-03-28 21:08:29
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1csvk3-00013I-Rx,2017-03-28 21:08:29
domain3.TLD
mx10.mailfilter.nl,1csbxg-0005sG-Px,2017-03-28 21:08:29
```

---

```
$ awk -F,  'NF==1 {h=$0} {(NF==1?k=1:t[h]=k++)} END {for (h in t) print h,t[h]}' f
domain2.TLD 4
domain1.TLD 2
domain3.TLD 1
```

In sorted order -

```
awk -F,  'NF==1 {h=$0} {(NF==1?k=1:t[h]=k++)} END {
> PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
> for (h in t) print h,t[h]}' f
domain1.TLD 2
domain2.TLD 4
domain3.TLD 1
```

Comment: awk -F,  'NF==1 {h=$0} {(NF==1?k=1:t[h]=k++)} END {for (h in t) print h,t[h]}' did the trick

Incomming delivery counter = 7. Mail from domains in queue are ***.com 1 ***.com 2 ***.com 1 ***.nl 1 ***.nl 1 ***.com 1

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many approaches, hope this helps:

```
echo -e "$totalcount" | grep -o domain | wc -l
```

grep with -o option means it prints every matched value of "domain" onto a separate output line and then count these newlines with wc -l.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/^domain[0-9]+\.TLD/{if(p)print p,c;p=$0;c=0;next}{c++}END{print p,c}' file
domain1.TLD 2
domain2.TLD 4
domain3.TLD 1
```

Explained:

```
/^domain[0-9]+\.TLD/ {  # domain*TLD records:
    if(p) print p, c    # print p revious domain and c ount
    p=$0                # reset vars
    c=0
    next                # next record
}
{ c++ }                 # count other records
END { print p, c }      # print the last domain*TLD
```